# Change font-color by clicking a button (JS function)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to change the font color of the “div” area to black by clicking on the button but none of the variations I’m trying work. Does anyone have any ideas? Could this be syntax related?

I guess it could be because I specify the div and the elements inside are not reached by the function. On the other hand it could be because I use `document.getElementById("black").style.color="black";` and the font is not directly addressed there. These are just some guesses of mine.

```js
function black() {
  document.getElementById("black").style.color = "black";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="eins">Farben</h1>


<p class="blau">1. blau</p>
<p class="pink">2. pink</p>

<h1 class="zwei">Sonnenfarben</h1>

<div id="black">
  <ul>
    <li class="rot">rot</li>
    <li class="orange">orange</li>
    <li class="gelb">gelb</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p class="braun">3. braun</p>
<p class="grau">4. grau</p>


<h1 class="drei">Grüntöne</h1>
<p class="teal">I. teal</p>
<p class="limegreen">II.limegreen</p>
<p class="green">III. green</p>

<button onclick="black()">Black</button>
```

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/koeddi/pen/WNzopZm

Comment: I did style it via css. (see codepen)

Comment: And at the other end of the link, the `li` elements have `color: something specific` not `color: inherit` so the black colour you assign to their grandparent div doesn't touch them (and there's no other text inside that div).

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Basic rules of CSS Specificity. You have a class that sets color. You set a grandparent, it will not overwrite the child.

Comment: Your CodePen has multiple problems. (1) you can't have a script tag with both an src and code and (2) applying black to the parent div will not override the classes applied to the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

- Here  is the main logic,
  `document.querySelectorAll("*")` this will select all ements of the `DOM` and you than I just loop through it using `forEach` loop.
- I made the change here  `document.querySelectorAll("#black *")` select all children of id `#black` and loop through it and then set color to black using `element.style.color="black"`.

```js
function black() {
  alert("This will only set all children of #black color to black");
  document.querySelectorAll("#black *").forEach(element => {
    element.style.color = "black";
  })
}

function setAllToblack() {
  alert("This will set all elements color to black");
  document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(element => {
    element.style.color = "black";
  })
}
```

```css
.eins {
  text-indent: 40px;
}

.zwei {
  text-indent: 75px;
}

.blau {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: blue;
}

.pink {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: pink;
}

.rot {
  text-indent: 70px;
  color: red;
}

.orange {
  text-indent: 70px;
  color: orange;
}

.gelb {
  text-indent: 70px;
  color: yellow;
}

.braun {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: brown;
}

.grau {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: grey;
}

.teal {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: teal;
}

.limegreen {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: limegreen;
}

.green {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">




</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="eins">Farben</h1>


  <p class="blau">1. blau</p>
  <p class="pink">2. pink</p>

  <h1 class="zwei">Sonnenfarben</h1>

  <div id="black">
    <ul>
      <li class="rot">rot</li>
      <li class="orange">orange</li>
      <li class="gelb">gelb</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <p class="braun">3. braun</p>
  <p class="grau">4. grau</p>


  <h1 class="drei">Grüntöne</h1>
  <p class="teal">I. teal</p>
  <p class="limegreen">II.limegreen</p>
  <p class="green">III. green</p>

  <button onclick="black()">Black</button>
  <button onclick="setAllToblack()">Set all elements color to Black</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I won't down vote, but this isn't a good solution nor does address the underlying problem.

Comment: I thought he want to change color for every element on page I have made change

Answer (score 1):

Your
`document.getElementById("black").style.color="black";`
is probably properly set to black,
but it doesn't have any text elements not wrapped in other tags inside of it.

You only have text elements in it which are in different tags,
and those tags have their own colors,
and those selectors (more specific ones) are more important,
so the color is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code Work fine it changing Div content color but inside div you have li which have separates styles so because of that their color is not changed but if you want to changed their color too then you need to get all li with their id or class and changed their color or you can also do that with you parent id like parent.children(i).style="color" in loop to change their color.[image]